# How do you get from this expression to the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Briefly, I am following the solution to a problem, which I understand up to the point where this expression is reached:

$$u_x = \frac{vy + \sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)}}{1 + y^2}$$

The solution then states that this is equivalent to:

$$u_x = \frac{c^2 - v^2}{\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} - vy}$$

My question is, how do you get from one to the other? It is possibly obvious, but I just can't see it and it's driving me insane.

Comment: $$a+b = \frac{(a+b)(a-b)}{a-b} = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}$$ where $a = \sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2-v^2)(1+y^2)}$ and $b = vy$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of your numerator. That is, multiply your function by $1$:

$$\frac{vy - \sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)}}{vy - \sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)}}$$

You lose the sqrare root sign in the numerator (you'll have a difference of squares in the numerator), which then simplifies quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something obvious, I'm kicking myself now.

Comment: It happens to all of us!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
u_x =& \frac{c^2 - v^2}{\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} - vy}\\\\
 =& \frac{\left(\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} + vy\right)(c^2 - v^2)}{\left(\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} - vy\right)\left(\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} + vy\right)}\\\\
=&\frac{\left(\sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)} + vy\right)(c^2 - v^2)}{(c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2) }\\\\
=& \frac{vy + \sqrt{(vy)^2 + (c^2 - v^2)(1 + y^2)}}{1 + y^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at what's different in the equation. In the second, there's a $-vy$ in the square root of the denominator. What does that mean must have happened?